# Declaring a big-sized 2d Double array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, exception, memory

I am trying to Declare a double 2d array in java as follows:

```
double [][]x=new double[640][15360];
```

but i get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried to increase the heap size from the project properties but i still get the same exception.

any tip?

Comment: Do you *have* to allocate the entire matrix up front? Is the data sparse?

Comment: That is indeed large; why don't you use a memory mapping instead (`DoubleBuffer.allocateDirect()`) or a mmap()ed file?

Comment: Can you use an arrayList?

Comment: @MagnusCaligo that won't change anything; in fact it will eat even more space

Comment: the data represent 20 folders of 32 photos of 128*120 pixels

Comment: Is it really necessary to keep all of them in memory at the same time?

Comment: And you store that in a _double array_??

Comment: @fge A ***multidimensional** double array*.

Comment: What heap size do you exactly set?

Comment: I need to convert this matrix to MATLAB, i am using JMatio library which requires to a double matrix in order to cast it to matlab type

Comment: Try passing one photo at a time, instead of trying to pass 640 photos at once.

Comment: I'm counting 80MB, and that should not be a problem. You could consider `float`, or even `byte` (if it's just pixel intensities in the range 0...255), but it should not be necessary.

Comment: I tried to make the heap up to 1024 and then up to 1500 but this didn't work

Answer (score 1):

This array isn't the problem.  By creating this array, you're allocating approximately 78MB (`640*15360*8 bytes`) which Java can handle just fine without adjusting the heapsize at all.  Try putting your array declaration in a `main` method on its own, it'll work just fine.

Something else you are doing is overloading your heap.

Comment: my friend, i tried putting the array declaration in the main method, but it didn't work fine, here is the trial:
http://i60.tinypic.com/95myah.png
i need to store the pixels of 128x120 image while having 32 images in each of 20 folders. i need to keep all of them in the array at once because i have to convert it as one block to MATLAB type using a library called JMatio

Comment: The code you pasted runs just fine for me (Eclipse 4.3, Java 7 with no VM flags, Windows 7).  Your problem is not with this array declaration, there is something else impacting your heap space.

Answer (score 0):

When I run this with the option `-Xmx128m` it runs fine.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] x = new double[640][15360];
        System.out.printf("%,d bytes allocated%n", x.length * x[0].length * 8);
    }
}
```

prints

```
78,643,200 bytes allocated
```

> I tried to make the heap up to 1024 and then up to 1500 but this didn't work

Most likely you are not setting the heap size correctly.

Comment: @AliSmart "I tried to make the heap up to 1024 and then up to 1500 but this didn't work "
Maybe you forgot the "m" after the number, like Xmx=1024m ?